# How should I learn Ext JS 4.2?

Tags: extjs

I've been assigned to a legacy project which runs on Ext JS 4.2. I know JavaScript but I'm totally unaware of Ext JS and I'm having trouble in understanding it. Can someone please guide me on how to learn Ext JS, what approach should be followed and the important topics to be covered? Or what sequence should be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using ExtJS (7.2.0) in a corporate project for six months, these are some tips I would have needed some time ago.

You should start from the official docs and examples given by Sencha:

- [guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/index.html#!/guide) --> the main topics are The Class Systems, MVC Application Architecture and Components, which are the basis of ExtJS;
- [examples](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/index.html#!/example) --> I find the KitchenSink example very useful, since you can briefly overview all the components available in the system - you can also give a look to MVC examples, in order to see more complex architectures;
- [forum](https://forum.sencha.com/forum/) --> you can also check out the Sencha forum, which has many interesting topics (many more that you can find here on Stack Overflow).

Since you are using an older version of ExtJS, you will find many materials on the internet, because it was widely used several years ago, while now it is difficult to find updated sources.

You can check out [Saki website](https://learnfromsaki.com/ext-examples/#tree-simplest) or [fiddle explorer](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/search) sorting by created date ASC:

[image: see example here]

Answer (score 0):

I used to be a trainer for Sencha, and I left the company in 2013 right around the time when ExtJS 4.2 was the main version.

The fastest way to get up to speed on the framework is to take a training class from Sencha. I haven't worked for Sencha for 8 years, and many of my colleagues (who I respected highly as trainers) aren't there any more, so this is not a plug for their services, but it's the fastest way. You will learn shortcuts that will take you much longer if you were to do it yourself. The framework is huge an complicated, and it's nice to get an overview of how it works from an experienced guide.

Before I was hired as a trainer, I took both the ExtJS and Sencha Touch classes that they had available, and the difference between the "before" and "after" in my understanding was huge. Yes, it's a week of your time, and yes, it's $2500, so your manager may not agree with my recommendation, but like I said, it's the fastest way to get up to speed.

If you do decide to take the class, spend some time with your legacy app and write down where you're getting stuck, and ask those questions in class. Part of the class value is that you can get some free light consulting for any issues you may be having.

The fact that you know Javascript is a big plus. I've had people in my classes who were new to Javascript, and that was another hurdle that they had to get over.

Good luck with your app!